# Angular Socket.io btford

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I am trying to use btford Angular-Socket-io and I am looking for the equivalent of socket.broadcast.emit (with Express).
I.e I want to emit a message to everyone

With the Express Socket.io I can control whether to broadcast to everyone or just one user but I do not know how with Angular-Socket-io
With Angular-Socket-io, I can only do  io.sockets.emit from the server.

I can't find any information on the net about this. Please help..

Comment: angular-socket-io is only really for the client. You can still use the normal syntax to broadcast to everyone from the server. Can you add code to your question to help us understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I just realised that Angular-Socket-Io is only for the client and everything else stays the same for the server. Cheers!